# How can I set two Visual Studio projects to be in the same folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I wrote a C# windows service project and a related setup project in the same solution named MailTrigger. But after I built the whole program, there is two folders, "MailTrigger" and "MailTriggerSetup"(as I named the setup project). My problem is how can I set the two project to be in the same folder?

Comment: Are you referring to the project files, or the binaries (dlls)

Comment: In which step and where should I refer to the project files?

Comment: Each project is stored in their own project folders, you cannot change them (this is how the solution keeps track of each project).

Comment: However, if what you are referring to are simply the dlls that are generated on compilation, then you can change the destination of the builds in Project Settings (DeploymentOutputPath or something similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a solution, you will have individual project directories under your solution directory. You have the ability with the setup project to tell it where to put the created binaries. I am not sure what specifically you are wanting, all of the files in one folder without any delineation between your main project and your setup?(which will not work) or just wanting your msi files in the same folder as your main projects code?

Edit: I was able to get a directory structure that looks like:
[image]

By moving the MailTriggerSetup Directory into the MailTrigger Directory and editing the MailTrigger.sln file's project settings with notepad to look like this, **also just change the file paths not the Guid's** :

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}")  = "MailTrigger", "MailTrigger\MailTrigger.csproj", "{FD22977F-584D-4707-9B10-35482B91C450}"
EndProject
Project("{54435603-DBB4-11D2-8724-00A0C9A8B90C}") = "MailTriggerSetup", "MailTrigger\MailTriggerSetup\MailTriggerSetup.vdproj", "{15C4C96E-EF6A-44DB-  BDFB-8AEE2C05289E}"
EndProject
```

**Some caution needs to be taken since you are directly editing the solution file, Please backup your data before trying this.**

Comment: My requirement is like that:
-MailTrigger
--MailTriggerSetup
----MailTiggerSetup.vdproj
----bin
----release
--bin
--others
--*.cs